# How can I get a UITableView to reload (or, why isn't reloadData working)?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a controller where the user searches for locations pulled from a Core Data store.  To keep the UI responsive I fetch the object IDs on a background thread, like so:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(fetchLocationIDsForSearchTerm:)
                           withObject:searchText];
}

-(void) fetchLocationIDsForSearchTerm:(NSString *) searchTerm
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = <a new context for this thread>        
    NSArray *locationIDs = <a CoreData query which returns object IDs>

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(didFetchLocationIDs:) withObject:locationIDs waitUntilDone:YES];
    [context release];
    [pool release];
}

-(void) didFetchLocationIDs:(NSArray*) theLocationIDs
{   
    NSMutableArray *newLocations = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSManagedObjectID *objectID in theLocationIDs)
    {
        [newLocations addObject:[[self managedObjectContext] objectWithID:objectID]];
    }

    self.locations = newLocations;
    [[self mainTableView] reloadData];
}
```

...and then I pull the data out of self.locations in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

I would expect that the table would update when the results come back; but instead, it seems to update when the user enters the next letter of their search.  Why isn't [[self mainTableView] reloadData] reloading the table?

UPDATE

I'm using a UISearchBar with SearchDisplayController.  If I remove the SearchDisplayController, the problem goes away.  Is there some property of the SearchDisplayController I should be using instead?

Comment: what is happening when you run this? can you elaborate on the errors you are seeing?

Comment: I type "Lee" and get back the locations starting with "Le".  Then I type another d and get back the locations starting with "Lee".

Comment: just an idea, since it also happened to me before. Are you REALLY sure that mainTableView is actually linked to your UITableView via XIB or in code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have two tables.

Table 1 is created by you.

Table 2 is created by the search display controller and is displayed above your table view while a search is taking place. (Read the Overview section of [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) carefully, it's tripped my up in the past with this very problem!)

Try changing your line to this :

```
[[[self searchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView] reloadData];
```